# Base class pointer calling non virtual base function which is virtual in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am learning C++ virtual functions. I declared a function as non virtual in base class, and same function as virtual in derived class. If i create base class pointer with derived object and call the function, it is calling base class function. How it is possible if that function is non virtual in base class?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
        public:
        void steer(){
                cout<<"Steering Vehicle";
        }
};

class Car: public Vehicle{
        public:
        virtual void steer(){
                cout<<"Steering car";
        }
};
int main(){
        Vehicle* v1=new Car();
        v1->steer();
        return 0;
}
```

**Current output**

```
Steering Vehicle
```

**Expected output**

```
Steering car
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: The base class function `steer` should be declared virtual, otherwise no virtual lookup will be done when you call `v1->steer()`.

Comment: Your base-class functions needs to be marked as `virtual`. That makes all overriding child-class functions `virtual` automatically, so you don't need the `virtual` keyword in the `Car` class. But I recommend you use the `override` specifier: `void steer() override { std::cout << "Steering car\n"; }`

Comment: @Aedoro you mean, the base class pointer which i am declaring should have that function as virtual, then only it will look for virtual  lookup?

Comment: Yes and then it is good practice to use `void steer() override { ... }` in your derived classes. See C++ core guidelines [C.128 Virtual functions should specify exactly one of virtual, override, or final](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final)

Comment: As a final note, in current C++ avoid the use of (naked) `new/delete` to avoid memory leaks. Use `#include <memory>` and `auto v1 = std::make_unique<Car>();`

Comment: if you remove all `virtual` from the code, what output would you expect? Why expect something different when adding back `virtual` on the derived only?

Comment: @PepjinKramer actually not even dynamic alloction is required for polymoprhism. `Car c;  Vehicle& v = c;`

Comment: `v1-steer()` will call `Vehicle::steer()` since `steer()` is a non-virtual member of `Vehicle` and `v1` is of type `Vehicle *`.    If you intend it to do a virtual call (i.e. resolve to `Car::steer()`) then `Vehicle` needs to declare `steer()` as `virtual`.     There is no way that `Car` can force `v1->steer()` to become a virtual call if `steer()` is not a `virtual` function of `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 2):

The current base class method `Vechicle::steer()` is actually **non-virtual**.
So the virtual method that you provided  in the derived class `Car::steer()`, is **not actually overrriding** the base class method.

To get your expected output, you can just *mark the base class method* `Vehicle::steer()` to be virtual as shown below.

Additionally, although **not necessarily needed but you can mark the method in the derived class** `override` as also shown below:

```
class Vehicle{
        public:
//------vvvvvvv----------------->added this virtual keyword to make this virtual 
        virtual void steer(){
                cout<<"Steering Vehicle";
        }
};
class Car: public Vehicle{
        public:
//------v------------------------->not necessary to use virtual and override keyword here 
        void steer() override     
        {
                cout<<"Steering car";
        }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rGKd5eTYa)

---

[Virtual functions should specify exactly one of virtual, override, or final](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final)